# Training on Google Colab is slower than on local machine despite having better GPU - why?

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory, torch

I've got a DL model to train and since the data is quite large I store it on my Google Disk which I mount to my Google Colab instance at the beginning of each session. However, I have noticed that the training of the exact same model with exact same script is 1.5-2 times slower on Google Colab than on my personal laptop. The thing is that I checked the Google Colab GPU and it has 12GB RAM (I'm not sure how can I check the exact model), while my laptop GPU is RTX 2060 which has only 6GB RAM. Therefore, as I'm new user of Google Colab, I've been wondering what might be the reason. Is this because data loading from mounted Disk Google with torch DataLoader slows down the process? Or maybe this is because my personal harddrive is SSD and Google Colab might not have SSD attached to my instance? How can I validate further if I'm not doing anything with my Google Colab setup that slows down the training?

Comment: It's just colab limitation on long processes. They may limit or even inhibit usage if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The resources for Google Colaboratory are dynamically assigned to user instances. Short, interactive processes are preferred over long running data loading and processes further info can be found in the documentation:

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#resource-limits

Specifically quoted from the above link

> "GPUs and TPUs are sometimes prioritized for users who use Colab interactively rather than for long-running computations, or for users who have recently used less resources in Colab...As a result, users who use Colab for long-running computations, or users who have recently used more resources in Colab, are more likely to run into usage limits"